# Fancybox Overlay Helper Doesn't work in IE8

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-8, fancybox-2

I am using the below script to have a overlay for my fancybox.  It works fine on firefox and safari but doesn't work in IE8.

```
helpers:  {
  overlay : {
   css : { 
   'background' : 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)',
   }}
},
```

I know rbga is not supported in IE8 and below so I tried below but getting javascript error.

```
    helpers : { 
        overlay : { 
            css : {
            'background' : 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)',
            'filter':'progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#a6000000,endColorstr=#00000000,GradientType=0)'
                }
     }}
```

Thx to the helps below I got it working.  Updated the script to the working version. Notice the **GradientType=0** is the key to get the opacity.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
helpers:  {
        overlay : {
            css : { 
            'background' : 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)',
            '-ms-filter' : 'progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#2F2727,endColorstr=#1a82f7)'
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: Does it show any errors in the console and hw about other browsers?

Comment: Make sure your browser renders in IE8 standards mode. Also can you try just `filter` instead of `-ms-filter` in the above code.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
helpers : { overlay : { 
css : {'filter':'progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#2F2727,endColorstr=#1a82f7)',
'zoom': '1',
'background' : 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)'
         }
         }
```